# NGUI set default object in the scrollview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am making a select wheel using NGUI scrollview and "UICenter on child". It works perfect as it is, but I would be like to be able to, when fired, to set a default item as the "selected / center" child? How can i accomplish that? Is there a parameter I can set for the scrollview?

Hoping for a little help in this matter and merry christmas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to tell the UICenterOnChild component what Transform you want to center on.  The easiest way to do this is to attach a small script to the scrollview that has the UICenterOnChild component and do something like:

```
public UICenterOnChild MyCenterOnChildObject;
public Transform SomeTransform;

void SetDefaultChild() {
    this.MyCenterOnChildObject.CenterOn(this.SomeTransform);
}
```